# Learning Scala as first 'functional' language?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Since Scala is a 'OO meets functional' language, is it a good idea for me to learn Scala as my first functional language as I know most OO concepts (from learning Java)?

Or would it be better if I learned a pure functional language such as Haskell, then mixed my knowledge of OO and functional programming together so I better understand Scala?

As functional programming is greatly different to what I'm used to, I want to make sure I learn the concepts in a way that I can transfer then between functional language to functional language and not get caught up on OO and functional concepts that only relate to Scala.

Comment: Annoying that this question has been put on hold as I wish I'd asked it and had it answered a year ago. Personally I would say learn Haskell, it's not as hard as people make out, you just need to be cool with the fact that you will be starting from scratch as if you don't know how to programme. I learnt FP using Scala at work but looking back I wish I had learnt Haskell instead. You need to make a switch in your brain, Haskell will force you to do that more quickly because it is the only way.  I would also recommend reading 'the little schemer', I wouldn't 'get' recursion without it.

Comment: I think this is more a question of your preferred learning style than anything else. In Scala you will be productive from day 1, but your first programs won't be very functional; you'll have to push yourself to gradually, incrementally adopt more idiomatic, functional techniques and not just stay in the OO comfort zone. In something like Haskell it'll be a lot more "sink or swim"; you will probably spend some days frustrated and unable to do anything before you "get it", but this may force you to learn more. Both approaches have their merits.

Comment: @shmish111 thats exactly what I was thinking. Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a language that exposes its FP traits more explicitly than Scala. You can still write OO code in Scala without dipping into FP at all.

If you want academic purity, go learn Haskell. The language now has a rich ecosystem and is gaining traction, and is definitely production ready, so you don't have to be afraid that what you learn will be lost. http://learnyouahaskell.com is a great starting point that is available for free on the web.

At some point in time you may want to learn a Lisp dialect. There's a whole plethora of them available today, with varying degrees of success, but you have probably heard of Clojure, which runs on top of JVM.

I am not aware of any good free resources, but I can recommend https://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure. The book is a little bit old - it covers version 1.3 and we're currently approaching 1.7 - but is still relevant, and goes straight to the point. Once you've gone through that you're ready for something meatier, like Fogus' 'The Joy of Clojure'.

There is also a great site full of short programming problems in Clojure, which I recommend that you check out - google for '4Clojure'.

Comment: I'm stuck between Haskell and Erlang, my University has lectured on the basics of Erlang but I've read in so many places that Haskell is a great language, any advice?

Comment: I've been writing Erlang code commercially for the past two years, and it's a great FP language that suits a particular problem domain - heavily concurrent, distributed applications with failover guarantees. The VM is rock solid. But while you can write a lot of stuff in it it's geared towards that particular problem domain. The interesting stuff in Erlang isn't FP, it's concurrent programming with message passing, isolated state, and supervision trees handling process failover. I'd leave that until after you've been exposed to FP concepts elsewhere, like in Haskell.

Comment: Perfect, Haskell it is.

Answer (score 2):

Scala is a pretty good first functional programming language.  I personally didn't understand Haskell until after learning Scala.  Learning Scala means the only new part is the functional programming part.  You don't have to worry about a drastically different syntax or type system, and you don't have to learn about monads just to do simple IO.  To make sure what you're learning is transferrable, don't use any `vars`, just `vals`.

At a certain point Scala's type system becomes unwieldy, as you dive into the abyss of implicits, covariance, and contravariance to try to use concepts such as monads.  At that point, you will have enough background in functional programming to switch to Haskell and *actually understand it*.  Haskell's type system is much better suited for such topics.

In other words, Scala makes beginner functional programming concepts easy, but advanced concepts harder, which makes it a very good gateway language.